# I want HIghlighted text to look bold

Tags: java, swing

When I select a piece of text in a JTextArea, it gets coloured in white and highlighted in blue (I'm using Nimbus LookAndFeel).

I changed it so the highlight is white, and the text also remains in black, so it is not noticed. What I want now is to get the text in bold when the user highlights it.

Is there any easy way to do this? Would it work if I create a listener for double-click, or would the text get bold but not highlighted at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `DefaultHighlighter` source
Inner class `DefaultHighlightPainter` has method

```
public void paint(Graphics g, int offs0, int offs1, Shape bounds, JTextComponent c)
```

You can specify font there. Just call setFont() for the Graphics instance.

NOTE: bold font could have different widht so you should use font like "Monospaced"

Answer (score 1):

Use a JTextPane, then you can use Styles for your hightlighted text. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html).