# Java apply HTML to a selected text

Tags: java, html, jtextpane, jeditorpane

I wanted to know if there is a way that I can apply basic HTML to a text pane or text editor using a Highlighter. My objective is to basically do a text editor using basic HTML. For example a user highlights a part of some text and clicks on a button and I want that to become bold for example, using html but without showing tags or anything, just the selected text in bold. Also I wanted to know if it is better to use a textpane for this or a editorpane and why. Thank you.

Comment: Java seems like the wrong tool for this job, you could probably do this fairly easily with javascript.

Comment: please take a look at the following questions; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610013/i-want-highlighted-text-to-look-bold - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400913/highlight-and-bold-text-in-jtextpane

Comment: Its not the same @yns read again.

Answer (score 0):

anyway, you have to set a HTMLDocument to your JTextPane. Then, you can use the features of HTMLEditorKit and HTMLDocument to achieve what you want. For instance you can use :

```
    insertHTML(jtp.getDocument(), jtp.getSelectionStart(), "<b>"+getSelectedText()+"</b>", 0, 0, HTML.Tag.B);
```

From the HTMLEditorKit. Something like that (I have not try the code)